# Detect and remove abnormal data from 1D data

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have a 1D data which represents order values. Sometimes a client creates a test order which they don't remove from the system. What would be the best way of detecting and removing values that seem to be abnormal in comparison to the rest of population?

Example (but actual) data:

`275.13
397.42
444.86
567.29
698.36
702.39
878.84
927.06
1054.11
1131.28
1289.93
1305.19
1456.22
1504.86
2962.27
3120.53
5122.78
6475.79
7236.47
28017.54 <- still correct value
33605.99 <- still correct value
3.6486887953E8  <- bad data
6.24847757422E9 <- bad data`

As far as I know other data sets haven't got as drastic distinction.

Initially I thought of clustering but as I only have a basic background in ML I hoped someone with more experience would be able to suggest something more appropriate for 1D data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clustering, look at **statistics**.

Clustering is too fragile, don't use it for automation.

The usual approach would be to take the mean and standard deviation, and then remove values outside of three standard deviations from the mean. Depending on your data, you may also want to use more than three, and if you have very noisy data, the median and MAD can work more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

k-means clustering, with 2 clusters, would probably work on the data you've provided. But so would eye-balling this data, and manually setting a threshold at say 1e6. It's unclear from the data example you've provided what challenges you are seeing that mean you can't just set a threshold by hand.

[edit] Given your additional information that there are 1000 customers, each with slightly different characteristics, I think you could consider using standard machine learning methodology of splitting your data into train/validate/test subsets.

You'll write your technique using the training set, which could be k-means clustering, or some variant on this, then validate on the validation set. Finally, occasionally you can test on the test set, to check that you didnt overfit on the validation set.

I suspect you wont entirely be able to escape from heuristics since, say there are 4 clusters, and they are clustered around for example: 10, 100, 10000, and 1e8. You, looking at this, know that the 1e8 cluster is an outlier, but only because you hvae the prior knowledge of knowing that the vast majority of your customers wont be making transactions for 1e8 dollars. Without such prior knowledge, there seems no obvious way, even as a human, of deciding which clusters are outliers?

Comment: Careful! What if there is no data to remove! K-means will nevertheless find two "clusters"

Comment: I wouldn't be able to set the threshold by hand because data for each of over 1k customers can be significantly different. E.g.Some might have orders of $300k that are valid but for others it would be an anomaly. I was told it's about 40GB of data so it wouldn't be easy to eye-ball. Aim is to have a system that runs once a week, detects bad orders, and returns total value of good orders per client. Initially I thought clustering would be good but I didn't realise they decided not to take into account things like whether an order was invoiced, paid or shipped. Hence we ended up with 1D data.

Answer (score 0):

This (imho) indeed falls under the field of statistics. As mentioned by @Anony-Mousse, taking the mean and sd, and next removing outliers which fall out of the 3sd range is the rule-of-thumb, $\textit{ad hoc}$ way of solving this.

You could go a step further and attempt to model the data using a distribution of choice. Taking the 3sd rule somewhat implies you are assuming the distribution is Gaussian, yet if you have other insights about the shape, spread, kurtosis etc., other distributions could also come into play.

Once modeled, one can then apply a statistical test of significance to assess how well a given e.g., sample fits into the distribution of choice (or out of it for that matter).